# check if popup is open to give focus and if not to open it

Tags: javascript, popup

I know there's a lot of 'check if popup is open' threads and I've tried versions of them all but I just cannot get anything to work- so forgive me if this seems like a duplicate question.

Basically, I have a button that opens a popup form. Often the user will minimize the popup. If they click the button again it needs to a) check to see if the popup is already open and, if so, un-minimize it and b) if the popup is not already open, open it.

This is the code and the button so it's clear how it's set up. I've tried code to check the if the url is open but haven't been able to get it to open the popup normally (if it's not already open). It'll just create a new tab. Any help would be really appreciated.

```js
function stopwatch(myURL, title, myWidth, myHeight) {
  var left = (screen.width - myWidth) / 2;
  var top = (screen.height - myHeight) / 4;
  var myWindow = window.open(myURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + myWidth + ', height=' + myHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
```

```html
<button class="shortbtnicon" type="button" onclick=" stopwatch ('https://example.com/shortcuts/stopwatch', 'MyPopUp', 450, 650);"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-1x"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this worked out, if anyone else needs the solution.

```js
var MyPopUp = false;
function stopwatch(myURL, title, myWidth, myHeight){
  //checks to see if window is open
  if(MyPopUp && !MyPopUp.closed)
  {
    MyPopUp.focus(); //If already Open Set focus
  }
  else
  {
    var left = (screen.width - myWidth) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - myHeight) / 4;
    MyPopUp = window.open(myURL, title,'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + myWidth + ', height=' + myHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);//Open a new PopUp window
  }
}
```